# Distinct select statement using two tables

Tags: mysql

I've looked around the forum for a while now, but I can't find a solution for the following.

I've got two tables, users and bookings.

users:

```
unique id, firstname and lastname
```

bookings:

```
uniquide id, userId, arrival and departure
```

For every booking a user makes, the bookings table will contain the unique users id in the field userId.
I now want to get the firstname and lastname from table users, and all bookings which are made depending on the userId.

```
select users.*, bookings.* FROM users, bookings WHERE bookings.userId =:id GROUP BY bookings.id
```

The statement above returns all bookings according to the userId, but it also contains the user itself multiple times, i just need the user data once.

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, b.id as bookingid, b.arrival, b.departure from users u JOIN bookings b ON u.id = b.userid
```

doing <kbd>GROUP BY</kbd> on booking.id makes no sense in this case, as booking.id is the lowest level element.  Now, you could group by users.id, but then you can no longer return all the individual bookings - but you can return a lot of helpful things like <kbd>COUNT(bookings.id) AS NbrBookings</kbd> or MIN(arrival) or MAX(departure)

but you can't have aggregate data and inidividual data at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
users.*, bookings.*
```

instead of this specify the relevant column names

Comment: good point, you should avoid using * to speed up your query and learn to get just the data needed.  Imagine if that table had 100 or 200 fields.